# hologram sim and sim800c module

Tags: serial-port, gsm, sim800

I recently got a sim800c to mess around with programming and mobile networks and purchased a hologram sim card. I am trying to build a program in node.js that sends "AT" commands to the board and can send text messages.

but I can't seem to get the hologram sim card to work with this gsm module

this is my first time really messing with gsm and AT commands and im not sure where to start

I have tried looking at the sim card registration with `AT+GREG?` and I just get `0,0` so I figured i somehow need to set the APN or something because hologram just says it's live not connected

so I tried `AT+CSTT="hologram","",""`
but I just get an error
doing `AT+CPIN?` just gives me `+CPIN: READY`
im new to this and am very confused on how to get this to work and get this gsm module connected to the network any pointers would be greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: First of all: are we sure that your SIM is active? If you place it in your phone do you successfully register to the network?

Comment: when I put it in my phone it will go active but with the gsm module it won't so I figured there must be some AT commands I need to figure out in order to register it each time it's powered on or something

Comment: So the SIM is ok. It's a start. Next step would be the PIN code, but you write it is ready. How do you check module's registration? I don't know `+GREG` command. I know `AT+CREG?` for circuit switched network (GSM) and `AT+CGREG?` for gprs network. Which one are you providing? Please, try also `AT+CEREG?`

Comment: ok so `AT+CPIN?` returns `+CPIN: READY` and `AT+CREG?` returns `+CREG: 0,2` and  `AT+CGREG?` and `AT+CEREG?` return errors

Comment: `+creg: 0,2` means that the registration is in progress. Wait at least 15 secs.

Comment: now its `+CREG: 0,0`

Comment: It surrendered... Just one stupid thing: is the antenna correctly connected?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I mean it just threads on

Comment: also `AT_COPS=?` just returns `+COPS: ,(0-4),(0-2)` do you think the antenna didn't get soldered right in the factory or something?

Comment: Yes, or maybe you have low signal. Or maybe... what is the command response of `AT+COPS?` ? Is it possible that you set something different by the default?